# How to know on which places there is a change in string?

Tags: string, kotlin

For example I have a string:

`val string1 = "My friend gave me a gift"`

and now this string is modified or edited

`val string1 = "My father gave me two gifts"`

how can I know at what places there is a change in the string or sentence?

I have been trying like this:

```
val oldString = prevString.split(" ")
val newString = currentText.split(" ")

for(i in oldString.indices) {
    if (oldString[i] != newString[i]) {
        oldText = oldString[i]
        newText = newString[i]
     }
}
```

but through this approach I am able to find only single changes in the string not multiple changes.
can anyone help me to find multiple changes in the string please?

Comment: Your doing was right, you just need use pair and list to store the change.

Comment: String searching algorithms can be quite complex. Your current solution will simply just compare words on same indexes, if that's what you want, just using `List<Pair<String, String>>` instead of `oldText` and `newText` will do, as already suggested. But what should happen in this case: `val s1 = "My friend gave me a gift"`, `val s2 = "My best friend gave me a gift"`? Your algorithm doesn't handle `insertions` really well, do you need that?

Comment: It looks like you may want an [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) algorithm, such as the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Computation). As Lukas says, this is likely to be pretty complex unless you can narrow down what you want.

Comment: Actually I wanted to delete one or more words from a sentence and write another words in place of those words and for that I was trying the above approach.

Answer (score 1):

Without more details it is not possible to come up with an algorithm which will produce the correct output each time. Even with an exact definition it probably will not be possible, because we are dealing with language(s).

If it is certain that the strings have the same amount of words when splitting by a space, then this would be a possibility:

```
val previousString = "My friend gave me a gift"
val currentText = "My father gave me two gifts"

val previousWords = previousString.split(" ")
val currentWords = currentText.split(" ")

val result = previousWords
  .minus(currentWords)
  .zip(currentWords.minus(previousWords))

println(result)
// Output: [(friend, father), (a, two), (gift, gifts)]
```

But you will soon get into trouble. An example:

```
val previousString = "My friend gave me a fantastic gift"
val currentText = "My father gave me two gifts"
```

Which produces:

```
[(friend, father), (a, two), (fantastic, gifts)]
```

... which of course is wrong. What about punctuation? What about apostrophes? etc. etc.